# Create histogram of count frequencies in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

Let's say I have the following data frame:

```
d = data.frame(letter = c(
    'a', 'a', 'a', 
    'b', 'b', 'b', 
    'c',
    'd', 'd', 'd', 'd',
    'e', 'e', 
    'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f',
    'g'))
```

How can I use `ggplot2` to make a histogram that does not count how many times a given letter occurs, but rather counts the number of times a given letter frequency occurs? In this example:

```
table(d$letter)

a b c d e f g 
3 3 1 4 2 7 1
```

two letters (c and g) occur once, one letter (e) occurs twice, two letters occur three times, etc. Such that you can make a figure equivalent to the base plot:

```
hist(table(d$letter), right = F, breaks = 6)
```

[image: base histogram]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert the result of `table` to a data frame and then use `ggplot`:

```
df <- as.data.frame(table(d$letter))
ggplot(df, aes(x = Freq)) +
    geom_histogram(binwidth = 1)
```

[image]

This works because the column containing the frequencies is by default called `Freq`:

```
head(df)
##   Var1 Freq
## 1    a    3
## 2    b    3
## 3    c    1
## 4    d    4
## 5    e    2
## 6    f    7
```

If you want to have the bars positioned between the integer numbers, you can use `center = 0.5` to center the bins at half integers. I also use `closed = "left"`, which is equivalent to `right = FALSE` in `hist()`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Freq)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 1, center = 0.5, closed = "left") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:7)
```

[image]